# Fetching data when two tables are related

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created two tables as shown in the diagram

[image]

I want to retrieve Name Address and SubjectName in a single stored procedure

I have written stored procedure as

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[prStudentFetchALL]
as
Select StudentId, Name, Address, SubjectId from [tbStudent]
```

I want to retrieve SubjectName instead of SubjectId

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` those tables:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[prStudentFetchALL]
as
Select S.StudentId, S.Name, S.Address, Sub.SubjectName 
from tbStudent S JOIN
     tbSubject Sub ON S.SubjectId =Sub.SubjectId
```

Learn more about `JOIN` at [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or [**blog.sqlauthority**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/).